# nodejs express regex/replace response

Tags: node.js, express, replace

When programming I use 'localhost'for local tests but in production I don't want to edit every file in a large project, I'm wondering if I can dynamically replace 'localhost' to servers ip '123.123.123.123' to save a ton of time. Here is some code that I've tried with no luck.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var express = require('express');
app.use(modify);
app.use(express.static('./files'));
function modify(req, res, next){
  res._send = res.send
  res.send = function(a) {
    a = a.replace('a', 'b');
    return res._send(a);
  }
  next();
}
http.listen(process.env.port, function () {
        console.log('listening on *:' + process.env.port);
});
```

I've also tried all of the other stack overflow posts with similar topics with no luck, any help would be greatly appropriated.

Comment: Running in development vs. Production Mode won't solve this for you?

Comment: The ip that I'm changing is the one that gets used in the html/js not what the nodejs uses.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this.  I'm privy to setting the `NODE_ENV` variable to the value of `"PROD"` on my production machines.  Then I can have code like this:

`let server = '123.0.0.1';
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "PROD") {
  server = 'localhost';
}`

Comment: I'm trying to replace the ip in the front end, not the backend.

Comment: @DrGoat I'm not sure I follow.  ExpressJS is a back-end only solution.  What problem are you trying to solve in the end?

Comment: ExpressJS is the webserver in my case, I'm trying to actively replace a string in the html and javascript (runs on front end) that express emits out to another string

Comment: I would fetch the string from the sever when the page first loads.  The server can be made aware of the environment it's in with the solution I mentioned.  A quick AJAX fetch on page load shouldn't be too heavy.  Another alternative is to render templated pages built using something like Pug or Mustache.  With templated pages, your server-side code can simply provide the correct string for the current environment.

Comment: What happens if the string was required on the index.html

Comment: How would it be required?  In a script tag? In a link tag, for a stylesheet? In an anchor or image tag?  The purpose of a template engine like Pug or Mustache is to build the HTML dynamically on the server side, then send it to the user as plain old HTML.